# Angular 4 Portal/CdkPortal not working in new child window

Tags: angular, typescript, window, portal

I'm working in an Angular 4 app and I need to show a specific component in a new child window. So I research for a solution (i'm NOT looking for a solution with routing by url 'couse my server always redirec to index with window.open('some URL'), so window.open('') with ataching might be the solution) and I found this stackblitz example
[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-window?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

in that example, are using `CdkPortal` . The problem is apparently cdk portal is not in angular 4 (I'm not shure, but this error is showing `@angular/cdk/portal"' has no exported member 'CdkPortal'`)

I just copy and paste the previous example 'couse is exactly what I need, but in my angular version is not working.

Is there some equivalent example for angular 4?

**ADITIONAL**

in the example, they are using this code fragment to show the window

```
<window *ngIf="showPortal">
  <h2>Hello world from amother window!!</h2>
  <button (click)="this.showPortal = false">Close me!</button>
</window>
```

so my question is... is posible to add other component inside the component that I want to atach in the portal? Something like this.

```
<window *ngIf="showPortal">
  <my-other-component [currentValue]="someValue"></my-other-component>
</window>
```

If it is posible, Would the component work correctly?

Comment: You can add another component to your component template, but you need to use `ng-container` directive instead of placing it inside the window component.

Comment: @Sergio Mendez have you checked my answer it helped u?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This will generate a child window without use of CdkPortal.

I have used generic window.open method to open a new window. also i have used name property of window to get reference of opened window.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component,ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef,Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { DynamicWindowComponent } from './dynamic-window/dynamic-window.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  injector: Injector;
  OpenWindow : any

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  open(): void {
    const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicWindowComponent);
    let componentRef  = componentFactory.create(this.injector);
    this.OpenWindow = window.open('', 'childwindow', 'width=400,height=400,left=150,top=200');
    this.OpenWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "";
    this.OpenWindow.document.body.appendChild(componentRef.location.nativeElement);
  }

  close(){
    this.OpenWindow.close()
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="open()">Dynamically Add Component</button>
```

**dynamic-window.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-window',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-window.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-window.component.css']
})
export class DynamicWindowComponent{
  close(){
    // get refence of child window by its name and close it
    let existingWin = window.open('', 'childwindow');
    existingWin.close();
  }
}
```

**dynamic-window.component.html**

```
<p>Dynamic Component</p>
 <button (click)="close()">Close me!</button>
```

Working example link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbapx4?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: is there any way to add `css` parent styles to the new created window?

Comment: @Kardon63 You can add this to your code `// STEP 5.1: clone stylesheets and style tags to external window
    document.querySelectorAll('link, style').forEach(htmlElement => {
      this.externalWindow.document.head.appendChild(htmlElement.cloneNode(true));
    });`

Comment: Okk, this is indeed copying all the styles but i am using a 3rd party library `devextreem`, but the styles copied to the new window are not applied to the component.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I used FormGroup in my DynamicWindowComponent: `17:47
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at resolveDep (vendor.js:58638)
    at createClass (vendor.js:)
    at createDirectiveInstance ( vendor.js:)
    at createViewNodes (vendor.js:)
    at createRootView ( vendor.js:)
    at callWithDebugContext (vendor.js:)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] ( vendor.js:)
    at ComponentFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create (vendor.js:)`